Unity 2D: new input system issue with JUMP Action via CallbackContext canceled
This is my code for Jump Action using the new input system:
/// JUMP action callback    
public void Jump(InputAction.CallbackContext context)
{
   if (context.performed)
   {
      //hold down button: full height JUMP
      rigidBody.linearVelocity = new Vector2(rigidBody.linearVelocity.x, jumpPower);
   }
   else if (context.canceled)
   {
      //light pressure: half height JUMP
      rigidBody.linearVelocity = new Vector2(rigidBody.linearVelocity.x, jumpPower * 0.5f);
   }
}

It works fine, but to avoid the player floating around, I also added a function that allows him to jump only if he is touching the ground. This is the function:
private bool isGrounded()
{
    if (Physics2D.OverlapBox(groundCheckPos.position, groundCheckSize, 0, GroundLayer))
    {
        return true; 
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}

Hence, I modified the jump function as follows:
/// JUMP action callback    
public void Jump(InputAction.CallbackContext context)
{
    if (isGrounded())
    {
        if (context.performed)
        {
            //hold down button: full height
            rigidBody.linearVelocity = new Vector2(rigidBody.linearVelocity.x, jumpPower);
        }
        else if (context.canceled)
        {
            //light pressure: half height
            rigidBody.linearVelocity = new Vector2(rigidBody.linearVelocity.x, jumpPower * 0.5f);
        }
    }
}

The issue is that now the jump is always FULL height, the light pressure is not working anymore. By debugging the code using some print statements, I observed that by performing the same action (i.e., slow button pressure for half jump) almost always Unity executes the *context.performed *action. Only rarely, it executes the half jump.
I only inserted a condition on a bool variable. I cannot figure out why it is not working correctly any more. Am I missing something?

Now the jump callback does nothing whenever the player is not on the ground, and presumably whenever the context is canceled (the player lets go of the button) they're not on the ground since they've just jumped. You'll have to rethink the logic, just doing light jump whenever jump button is released is too simplistic in any case.

Yep.. so, you most likely want if context.performed and isgrounded then jump if cancelled then apply some pressure, or give your rb a bit more mass so it has more inclination to be grounded curious you set velocity not add force
